Matching items of two list of the same size in an Ansible loop
I have two registered variables, both with equal number of lines, in Ansible.
register_1.stdout_lines has below output
1
2
...
120

register_2.stdout_lines has below output
one
two
...
one hundred twenty

I would like to match the first value of register_1.stdout_lines with the first value of register_2.stdout_lines, the second value of register_1.stdout_lines with the second value of register_2.stdout_lines and go on till 120.
Expected output:
1 one
2 two
... ...
120 one hundred twenty

I tried with a loop, but I am getting an output as:
1 one
1 two
1 three
...


Matching two list of the same size is something you would do with the zip filter:
Given:
- name: Spell out numbers
  ansible.builtin.debug:
    msg: "{{ item.0 }} {{ item.1 }}"
  loop: "{{ register_1.stdout_lines | zip(register_2.stdout_lines) }}"
  loop_control:
      label: "{{ item.1 }}"
  vars:
    register_1:
      stdout_lines:
        - 1
        - 2
        - 3
        - ...
        - 120
    register_2:
      stdout_lines:
        - one
        - two
        - three
        - ...
        -  one hundred twenty

You will get an output of:
ok: [localhost] => (item=one) => 
  msg: 1 one
ok: [localhost] => (item=two) => 
  msg: 2 two
ok: [localhost] => (item=three) => 
  msg: 3 three
ok: [localhost] => (item=...) => 
  msg: '... ...'
ok: [localhost] => (item=one hundred twenty) => 
  msg: 120 one hundred twenty


And if you need it as a big blob of text, you can join the lists back together:
- name: Spell out numbers
  ansible.builtin.debug:
    msg: "{{ register_1.stdout_lines
              | zip(register_2.stdout_lines)
              | map('join', ' ')
              | join('\n') }}"
  vars:
    register_1:
      stdout_lines:
        - 1
        - 2
        - 3
        - ...
        - 120
    register_2:
      stdout_lines:
        - one
        - two
        - three
        - ...
        -  one hundred twenty

Which gives:
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: |-
    1 one
    2 two
    3 three
    ... ...
    120 one hundred twenty


Except the loop here is not really needed. To have the expected output, we can simply use "{{ register_1.stdout_lines | zip(register_2.stdout_lines) | flatten }}"

@AlexanderPletnev the title of the question « in a loop » conflict with the expected output. So, indeed I am answering the question title for now.

Thank you @β.εηοιτ.βε and works like a charm!!
